# Bound on probability of bi-variate chi-square distribtuion

Tags: probability, chi-squared, bivariate-distributions

If I have two random  variables $u_1 = x_1^2$ and $u_2 = x_2^2$ where $x_1,x_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $E(x_1x_2) = \rho$. The what is the pdf or bound on the pdf of  $P(u_1<c,u_2>c)$?
Edit: The covariance matrix is $\sum$ where $\sum (1,1) =\sum (2,2) =1$ and $\sum (1,2) =\sum (2,1) = \rho$.

Comment: Is $(x_1,x_2)$ jointly normal?

Comment: Yes. the covariance matrix is given as $\sum (1,1)=\sum (1,1) =1$ and $\sum (1,2)=\sum (2,1) =\rho$. where $\sum$ is the covariance matrix.

Comment: I will add it in the question.